# Why does my HTTP request return status code 200 and redirection instructions?

Tags: html, objective-c, http, web, httprequest

When querying a website I get the following response:

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 15 Apr 2014 13:35:20 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = nginx;
    "Set-Cookie" = "SESSID=kvccccc; expires=Sat, 14-Jun-2014 13:35:20 GMT; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=.xxxxxxxx.com; HttpOnly";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.10";
} }
```

and the following data in the body:

```
{"status":"redirect","url":"\/terminal"}
```

What kind of redirection is this? I thought redirection has a status code beginning with a `3`. In my case, I get a status code of `200`. How should I handle this response in my app?

BTW: I am developing an iOS / Mac OS X app using Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webservice is returning this in the body: it's not part of the header. In fact, you get a 200 OK from the server, there's no real redirection here.

So, you should treat it as usual data.

Comment: When I continue with loading the next URL (`/terminal`), I get a response of: `Status: Redirect... Authentication Error`. How is this posible?

Comment: @AlexR Trying to generate bitcoins...? Well. As the status code says, you need to authenticate to access this page. If you're not logged in, it'll redirect you to the connection page. Open a tab on hitbtc.com/terminal in your browser to verify this.

Comment: I have authenticated successfully in the previous URL request. Authentication and URL loading worked fine. It returned the status code 200 including the fancy redirect data in the body.

Comment: @AlexR It's a bit off the question scope now: you follow their custom redirect intructions, it doesn't work, I have no idea why. Sorry!